# animating a div to slide from right side

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-animate, css-float

I am a beginner in web designing. i have a navigation bar on right side. i have defined class for li. i want all my li to animate and appear from right side.

i am unable to do that. need some help. my html and css code are.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
<script src="jquery.js"> </script>
<script>
$(function(){
    $(".content-box-blue").animate({width:'350px'},1200);
    $(".content-box-gray").animate({width:'250px'},1200);
    $(".content-box-green").animate({width:'300px'},1200);
    $(".content-box-purple").animate({width:'400px'},1200);
    $(".content-box-red").animate({width:'200px'},1200);
    $(".content-box-yellow").animate({width:'250px'},1200);
});
</script>
<title>Demo</title>
</head>
<body>
<header>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li class="content-box-blue"> </li>
        <li class="content-box-gray"> </li>
        <li class="content-box-green"> </li>
        <li class="content-box-purple"> </li>
        <li class="content-box-red"> </li>
        <li class="content-box-yellow"> </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<footer>
</footer>
```

css code for li are

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: right;
}
li {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
nav {
float: right;
width: 400px;
height: 500px;
margin-top: 35px;
margin-right: 10px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.content-box-blue {
background-color: #00bfff;
border: 1px solid #afcde3;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-left: 50px;
border-top-left-radius: 8% 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 8% 50%;
}
.content-box-gray {
background-color: #FF69B4;
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-left: 150px;
border-top-left-radius: 12% 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 12% 50%;
}
.content-box-green {
background-color: #3CB371;
border: 1px solid #b2ce96;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-left: 100px;
border-top-left-radius: 9% 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 9% 50%;
}
.content-box-purple {
background-color:#9370DB;
border: 1px solid #bebde9;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
border-top-left-radius: 6% 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 6% 50%;
}
.content-box-red {
background-color: #FF0000;
border: 1px solid #e9b3b3;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-left: 200px;
border-top-left-radius: 13% 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 13% 50%;
}
.content-box-yellow {
background-color: #FFA500;
border: 1px solid #fadf98;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-left: 150px;
border-top-left-radius: 12% 50%;
border-bottom-left-radius: 12% 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add following css in your stylesheet.

`li{
    clear:right;
    float: right;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You can do a float right on `<li>`'s

here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/reigel/4kVxE/)

Comment: float:right; on doing this it does not start animating my colored box from its position

Answer (score 0):

Change all `border-left-radius` to `right` radius and `float:left` to `right`

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
float: left;
}
li {
margin: 0; 
padding: 0;
margin-bottom: 20px;
}
nav {
float: left;
width: 400px;
height: 500px;
margin-top: 35px;
margin-right: 10px;
background-color: #ffffff;
}
.content-box-blue {
background-color: #00bfff;
border: 1px solid #afcde3;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-right: 50px;
border-top-right-radius: 8% 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 8% 50%;
}
.content-box-gray {
background-color: #FF69B4;
border: 1px solid #bdbdbd;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-right: 150px;
border-top-right-radius: 12% 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 12% 50%;
}
.content-box-green {
background-color: #3CB371;
border: 1px solid #b2ce96;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-right: 100px;
border-top-right-radius: 9% 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 9% 50%;
}
.content-box-purple {
background-color:#9370DB;
border: 1px solid #bebde9;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
border-top-right-radius: 6% 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 6% 50%;
}
.content-box-red {
background-color: #FF0000;
border: 1px solid #e9b3b3;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-right: 200px;
border-top-right-radius: 13% 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 13% 50%;
}
.content-box-yellow {
background-color: #FFA500;
border: 1px solid #fadf98;
height: 50px;
width: 0px;
margin-right: 150px;
border-top-right-radius: 12% 50%;
border-bottom-right-radius: 12% 50%;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/r4CVs/1/)**

Comment: doing this shift the navigation box to the left side of the page. i want the navigation box to be on right side. and all the colored box to animate from their position from the right.